# Setting moving default start and end Date in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a power BI report that need A default start date of two weeks ago and end date of Today. However, I also want the user to select other date ranges from the slicer if they want. Is there a way I can achieve it with power BI slicer?
[image]

If yes How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a **second slicer** to switch between your **default date period** (separate date table) and a **custom date period**.

```
Date Periods = 
UNION(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        DATESBETWEEN('Calendar'[Date], TODAY() - 13, TODAY()),
        "Type", "Default"
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(MIN('Calendar'[Date]),MAX('Calendar'[Date])),
        "Type", "Custom"
    )
)
```

Plus you need a **measure** to filter your first slicer depending on the selection.

```
Slicer Filter = 
IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE('Date Periods'[Type]) = "Custom",
    1,
    0
)
```