# Setting starting and ending values of a filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the a month slicer based on month number, I want to create a filter with the between format like below :

[image]

By default, when loading the report the left side will have the value of 1 (the month number of January) and the right side will have the value of the current month (the month number of October in this case)

Comment: You cannot set the min and max values of a filter. They are automatically picked from the data.

Comment: @Gangula I think it is possible using a measure maybe like in this example ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68610626/setting-moving-default-start-and-end-date-in-power-bi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a table using this below code-

```
month_list = GENERATESERIES(1,MONTH(TODAY()))
```

Now create the slicer using the Value column. Output will be as below-

[image]