# When I try to Set my Power BI "Slicer" to a "Between" Range and set the End Date as the MAX Date where Colum is not null, I get Circular Dependency

Tags: powerbi, max, circular-dependency, between, slicers

I followed the instructions from this question.

[Setting moving default start and end Date in power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68610626/4802489)

It works correctly, but I'm trying to set my Default End Date, as the MAX Date where a Integer Column is not null.

I created the following Measure:

```
last_date = CALCULATE(MAX('App Arrivals'[ReportDate]), 'App Arrivals'[Actual] <> BLANK())
```

When I try to Update the table with the Default Range for my second slicer:

```
ArrivalsPeriods = 
UNION(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        DATESBETWEEN('Datelist'[Date], [last_date] - 60,[last_date]),
        "Type", "Default"),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(MIN('Datelist'[Date]),MAX('Datelist'[Date])),
        "Type", "Custom"
    )
)
```

I got this warning message :

**A circular dependency was detected: ArrivalsPeriods[ArrivalsPeriods], 04cbb961-419a-41ac-9c6e-8b4e8201b23b, ArrivalsPeriods[Date], ArrivalsPeriods[ArrivalsPeriods].**

And It doesn't allow me to link that ArrivalPeriods Table with the Arrivals Table for filtering.

I'm trying to set the MAX Date filtered by a not null column value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to avoid the Circular Dependency and the `CALCULATE` function with this `MAXX` Dax Function.

```
MostRecentDate = MAXX(FILTER('App Arrivals', 'App Arrivals'[Actual] <> BLANK()),'App Arrivals'[ReportDate])
```